# MySQL query not getting executed in Dbeaver

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query which inserts data into the publishers table:

```
USE PROJECT;

INSERT INTO publishers (email, display_name, first_name, last_name, phone, website, assigned_to, favorite) VALUES ('DorothyJUnzueta@gmail.com', 'Dorothy Unzueta', 'Dorothy', 'Unzueta', '7428730894', 'www.yahoo.com', 'johndoe783@gmail.com', 'false');
```

But when I execute it in Dbeaver I am getting this error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO publishers (email, display_name, first_name, last_name, phone, websi' at line 3

Error position: line: 2
```

I am not able to understand where the error is present.

Please comment if further information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If favorite is of type boolean then you must remove the quotes:

```
INSERT INTO publishers (email, display_name, first_name, last_name, phone,
                        website, assigned_to, favorite)
VALUES ('DorothyJUnzueta@gmail.com', 'Dorothy Unzueta', 'Dorothy', 'Unzueta', '7428730894', 
        'www.yahoo.com', 'johndoe783@gmail.com', false);
```

Comment: Favorite is of type varchar(255), not boolean

Comment: Can you please provide the create statement